# mysql select rows on comma seperated value in column

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I've a product table with three columns:

1. product_id
2. product_name
3. product_keywords

And it contains values something like that:

> product_id | product_name | product_keywords
>   1                |Computer         |pc, computer, laptop, personal computer, desktop computer
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
>   2               |Mobile                |Smart Phone, Phone, Nokia, Sony
>   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'

Now I need an SQL query that if any customer search for pc or personal computer it will return product_name = Computer with product_id = 1 and so on.

Comment: You can use `like`, but better is to redesign your database (ech keyword own DB row). You chose the way to hell.

Comment: You can use FIND_IN_SET function of mysql

Comment: like will not going to work properly. Because I want to search in comma separated values. - @panther

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although my first instinct would be to re-design the schema to have a `keywords` table with unique values and a mapping table between the products and the keywords, MySQL actually offers an elegant way to query comma-delimited strings with the [`find_in_set`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function:

```
SELECT product_id, product_name
FROM   products
WHERE  FIND_IN_SET ('pc', keywords) > 0 OR
       FIND_IN_SET ('personal computer', keywords) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [find_in_set](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set).

```
select * from `table` where find_in_set(' Computer',product_name)
```

But storing values as csv is very bad database design.

Comment: this will not work because there is a space after each comma you need to replace this space then `find_in_set` will be able to work

Answer (score 0):

In it's simplest form you could write something like this.

```
SELECT product_id, product_name 
FROM    test
WHERE   product_keywords like '%computer%';
```

But this is not that safe because you could have keywords on multiple rows that contain the letters 'computer'.

If you can strip the spaces out of your keywords so it reads:

pc,computer,laptop,personal computer,desktop computer

then you can use the following code and be guaranteed the correct result:

```
SELECT product_id, product_name 
FROM    test
WHERE   CONCAT(',',product_keywords,',') like CONCAT(',%','computer','%,');
```

just replace 'computer' with a variable containing the users input. The comma's help to ensure to search on the full keyword and not just part of it.